# How to get an object pointer if I have the object's address as NSString?

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have the address of an object that I get as NSString (for example "0x1c42633c0"). How could I get pointer to an object from that?

I searched far and wide, but haven't found any question here describing the same problem, only saw people asking about going the other way around - getting address of an object they have a pointer to.

Comment: How does your "address" looks like and where did you get this NSString?

Comment: Added it to the question. In the specific case I need it for right now I get the memory string from XCode Instruments Allocations, but this issue seems interesting to me in general.

Comment: Why do you have an object's address as a string? What is the original issue you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you ever would have a pointer as a string, but you can certainly do it. You convert the string to binary and then use a cast to the type you want. Note that the app will crash if the address is invalid.

```
// Change NSObject to your desired class
NSString *stringAddress = @"0x123456789";
unsigned long long hexAddress;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringAddress] scanHexLongLong:&hexAddress];
NSObject *p = (__bridge id)(void *)hexAddress;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I never wanted it to be safe, just to use for debugging.